# Replace price shortcode with actual price from array

Tags: php, regex

I have a price shortcode like these:

```
[price ELEPHANT]
[price MONKEY_345]
[price TIGER.3TAIL]
```

where the word in caps (with the extension, if any) is the product SKU.

I've run a database query for SKU and PRICE, so now I want to replace the shortcode in my text to the actual price of the item.

`[price ELEPHANT]` becomes `46.97`

1.) I have been working with preg_replace, but can't get it to work with "." or "_" in the SKU:

```
$text = '<p>We have the price: [price CANOPY3.75B]. This is some more text.</p>';
$pattern = '/\[(\w+) (\w+)\]/';
$replacement = '$2';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $text);
```

2.) Once I identify the shortcode SKU value, how do I use it to search the array for the associated price?

(Hope I did the code blocks OK -- this is my first post here.)

Comment: Look up `preg_replace_callback()`.

Comment: looked at preg_replace_callbak() but having trouble wrapping my head around it. How to sort thru my array?

Comment: use (.+?) instead of (\w+) because ".","_" are not a word character

Comment: Thanks Can! That solves item #1 -- how do I use the callback feature to search my query array for the matching SKU so I can get the price?

Comment: @CanGeliş: `_` is a word character.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have the following array with the "name-price" pairs:

```
$prices = array('ELEPHANT' => 46.97, 'CANOPY3.75B' => 20.35, 'TIGER.3TAIL' => 30 ... etc.);
```

Then you can use the following piece of code:

```
$prices = array('ELEPHANT' => 46.97, 'CANOPY3.75B' => 20.35, 'TIGER.3TAIL' => 30,);

$text = '<p>We have the price: [price CANOPY3.75B]. This is some more text.</p>';
$pattern = '/\[price (.*?)\]/';
echo preg_replace_callback($pattern, 
        function($match)
        { 
            global $prices;
            return isset($prices[$match[1]]) ? $prices[$match[1]] : $match[1]; 
        }, 
        $text);
//output: We have the price: 20.35. This is some more text.
```